# GWT Command Injection

Tags: gwt, owasp

Is there a fix to overcome command injection (OWASP [CWE-77](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/77.html)) caused by usage of com.google.gwt.user.client.Command (GWTv2.4)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need. The GWT class `com.google.gwt.user.client.Command` is not the kind of "command" that can be injected in that class of attack.